# Structuring Flask App with a Helper Class

Tags: python, flask

In order to simplify the __init__.py main module, I want to push helper functionality to a different file/class. This requires passing many flask extensions instances when initializing the class, which seems inelegant. My current structure is as follows:

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request    
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
from FEUtils import FEUtils

# .. and more imports of various extensions ..

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app) 
mail = Mail(app)

fe_utils = FEUtils(db,mail,app.config)

# Flask code..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and FEUtils.py:

```
from models import User

class FEUtils(object):

    def __init__(self,db,mail,config):
        self.session = db.session # to access database
        self.mail = mail          # to send emails
        self.config = config      # to access app config dictionary


    def count_users(self): # example helper method
        return self.session.query(User).count()
```

This all works fine, but seems cumbersome. I'd like the helper class to inherit the various extension instances from the main module, and be able to access the flask config parameters from within the helper class, without passing each when the helper class is instantiated.

Asked differently, is there a way to have the helper class behave as if each of its methods was defined in the main module in an elegant way?

Comment: Without totally understanding your usecase, and this may be somewhat overkill, have you considered writing a Flask extension?

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/

Comment: @mam8cc, an extension would have a specific purpose. My question is regarding a generic way to structure and write a flask app, while pushing generic helper functionality away from the main module (e.g., login, registration, database queries), in a simple, more elegant way. Currently, the instantiation of such a helper class requires passing every relevant variable/instance through the module's `def __init__`.

Comment: Could you not import from the module: `from app import db, mail, app`?  I guess you couldn't use it in the __init__.py then?